# Simplifying code into one line with Dictionaries and List Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Ok this might be a stupid question but

if I wanted to simplify this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(e)):
    if int(e[i]) % 2 == 0 and i % 2 == 0:
        print("double even")
    elif int(e[i]) % 2 != 0 and i % 2 != 0:
        print("double odd")
    else:
        print("try again")
```

all into one line with a dictionary and list comprehension, how would I do it?

Comment: Well, you could ... but why? It won't be pretty.

Comment: This code doesn't create a list. Why would you want to use a list comprehension? That is what they are for - creating lists.

Comment: @sj95126 I specialize in making stupid decisions for fun and also torturing myself

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit more readable using `enumerate` and chained comparisons, for example:

```
for index, item in enumerate(e):
    if index % 2 == item % 2 == 0:
        print("double even")
    elif index % 2 == item % 2 == 1:
        print("double odd")
    else:
        print("try again")
```

You can make it even smarter by using the fact that you are actually interested in the sum of `i % 2` and `e[i] % 2`:

```
descriptions = ["double even", "try again", "double odd"]
for index, item in enumerate(e):
    print(descriptions[index % 2 + item % 2])
```

Or you can make it a one-liner, which is a nightmare to read:

```
print("\n".join(["double even", "try again", "double odd"][i%2+j%2] for i, j in enumerate(e)))
```